# How do I set a different language for a single word/sentence/paragraph in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word-365

I'm using Word 365. If my document is in English but a single word/sentence/paragraph is a different language Word usually will mark it (spelling).

How do I change the language just for that word/sentence/paragraph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expending on Reddy Lutonadio's [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1504250/201818): the solution was, that only one language was installed in the first place. Going through the Ribbon => Review => Language => Language Preferences...

[image]

You can see that there is only one language installed:

[image]

Installing a second language will make the language field in the status bar appear.

[image]

This is as long as the default settings haven't been changed so the language field is still suppose to be shown.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Select the word/sentence/paragraph.
2. Click on the language button on the bottom of the screen (status bar). You will see for example "English UK" (or any other language).
3. The "Language" window appears. Select the language of the word. Click OK.

Comment: I don't have a language option on the status bar, only word/page-count and spelling in the left corner and layout options in the right corner. And clicking on the spelling symbol in the status bar doesn't give me any language options.

Comment: @Albin Right-click on the status bar and select Language

Comment: it's selected (checkmark) still not possilble to choose a language, can you add a screenshot?

Comment: @Albin What happens if you try to hide the options that are on the status bar (word count, page, etc)? Are you able to hide, then show them again?

Comment: yes, they all work, only language is not shown